# How do I implement JS data into my CRUD app with ruby on rails? How do i use AJAX to tabulate showing content?

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, crud, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am fellow rubyist. I am a junior programmer. I have created an app where a user can post picture along with a caption and add hashtags to it. The name of the model is Muse for code reference.

Everything seems to be working. On the show page I can get the caption to show along with the pictures and the hashtags. What I am looking to do is to tabulate the contents so that when a user clicks on a muse the hashtag button/link the content will show, same goes for the caption. That said I realize that I am going to need ajax to load the content into a div. i am familiar with the process but for some reason i don't feel confident implementing it. Could anyone help me understand what is happening with AJAX, the CRUD and the JQUERY.

rails 4.2 
ruby 2.2.3

Also links are welcomed. :) Suggestions like learning a front-end framework like angular would be greatly appreciated.

here is my code below

MODEL(Muse = Picture + Caption/body + hashtags(not yet implemented))

```
class Muse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: '184x160>', large:'486x486'}
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

Controller

```
class MusesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_author!
  before_action :find_author, only: [:index, :create]
  before_action :find_muse, only: [:destroy]

  def index
    @author = current_author
    @muses = Muse.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def show
    @author = current_author
    @correct_author = Author.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @author_profile_picture = @correct_author.profile_pictures.last
    @muses = @correct_author.muses.all
  end

  def new
    @author = current_author
    @muse = Muse.new
  end

  def create
    @muse = Muse.new(muse_params)
    @muse.author_id = current_author.id
    if @muse.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end


  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @muse.update(muse_params)
      redirect_to @muse, notice: "You have successfully updated your muse"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @muse.destroy!
      redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def find_author
     @author = current_author
  end

  def find_muse
    @muse = Muse.find_by(params[:id])
  end

  def muse_params
    params.require(:muse).permit(:body, :image, :author_id)
  end
end
```

View

```
<div class="col-md-4 muse-home-panel">
  <div class= 'muses-scroll-container' >
    <% if !@author.muses.any? %>
  <div class="muse-empty-style">
    <h5>Muses</h5>
     <p> Just make sure it's all here</p>
    <div class="thumbnail muse-empty-thumbnail">
    <%= link_to 'Add Your Muses', new_muse_path, class:'create-new-link-style-2' %>
    <%= link_to '', new_muse_path, class:'glyphicon glyphicon-plus add-muse-icon' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% else %>
  <% @author.muses.each do |muse| %>
  <div class ='muse-container'>
      <%= image_tag muse.image.url(:large), class:'muse-style' %>
      <div class="muses-hashtag">
        <span>hashtags</span>
      </div>
      <!--
      <div class="muse-caption-container">
        <div>caption:<%= muse.body %></div>
      </div> -->
  </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have and I get the general concept but I have yet to see a full-fledge explained tutorial

Comment: there are plenty of full-fledged tutorials, there is no point making a new one just to answer your question

Comment: @maxpleaner ok! I will get looking. Thanks